# Queryable unbound amount of items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've been thinking a lot about the possible strategies of querying unbound amount of items.

For example, think of a forum - you could have any number of forum posts categorized by topic. You need to support at least 2 access patterns: post details view and list of posts by topic.

```
// legend
PK = partition key, SK = sort key
```

While it's easy to get a single post, you can't effectively query a list of posts without a scan.

```
PK = postId
```

Great for querying all the posts for given topic but all are in same partition ("hot partition").

```
PK = topic and SK = postId#addedDateTime
```

Store items in buckets, e.g new bucket for each day. This would push a lot of logic to application layer and add latency. E.g if you need to get 10 posts, you'd have to query today's bucket and if bucket contains less than 10 items, query yesterday's bucket, etc. Don't even get me started on pagionation. That would probably be a nightmare if it crosses buckets.

```
PK = topic#date and SK = postId#addedDateTime
```

---

So my question is that how to store and query unbound list of items in "DynamoDB way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got a good understanding about your options.

I can't profess to know the One True Way™ to solve this particular problem in DynamoDB, but I'll throw out a few thoughts for the sake of discussion.

> While it's easy to get a single post, you can't effectively query a list of posts without a scan.

This would definitely be the case if your Primary Key consists solely of the `postId` (I'll use `POST#<postId>` to make it easier to read).  That table would look something like this:

[image]

This would be *super* efficient for the 'fetch post details view (aka fetch post by ID)" access pattern.  However, we haven't built-in any way to access a group of Posts by topic.  Let's give that a shot next.

There are a few ways to model the one-to-many relationship between Posts and topics.  The first thing that comes to mind is creating a secondary index on the `topic` field.  Logically, that would look like this:

[image: posts by topic]

Now we can get an item collection of Posts by topic using the efficient `query` operation.  Pagination will help you if your number of Posts per topic grows larger.  This may be enough for your application.  For the sake of this discussion, let's assume it creates a hot partition and consider what strategies we can introduce to reduce the problem.

**One Option**

You said

> Store items in buckets, e.g new bucket for each day.

This is a great idea!  Let's update our secondary index partition key to be `<topic>#<truncated_timestamp>` so we can group posts by topic for a given time frame (day/week/month/etc).

[image: Posts by topic and truncated timestamp]

I've done a few things here:

1. Introduced two new attributes to represent the secondary index PK and SK (GSIPK and GSISK respectively).
2. Introduced a truncated timestamp into the partition key to represent a given month.  For example, `POST#1` and `POST#2` both have a `posted_at` timestamp in September.  I truncated both of those timestamps to `2020-09-01` to represent the entire month of September (or whatever time boundary that makes sense for your application).

This will help distribute your data across partitions, reducing the hot key issue.  As you correctly note, this will increase the complexity of your application logic *and* increase latency since you may need to make multiple requests to retrieve enough results for your applications needs.  However, this *might* be a reasonable trade off in this situation.  If the increased latency is a problem, you could pre-populate a partition to contain the results of the prior N months worth of a topic discussion (e.g. `PK = TOPIC_CACHE#<topic>` with a list attribute that contains a list of postIds from the prior N months).

[image]

If the `TOPIC_CACHE` ends up being a hot partition, you could always shard the partition using calculated suffix:

[image: cache of caches!]

Your application could randomly select a TOPIC_CACHE between 1..N when retrieving the topic cache.

There are numerous ways to approach this access pattern, and these options represent only a few possibilities.  If it were my application, I would start by creating a secondary index using the Post topic as the partition key.  It's the easiest to implement and would give me an opportunity to see how my application access patterns performed in a production environment.  If the hot key issue started to become a problem, I'd dive deeper into some sort of caching solution.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that watching Rick's talks 2-3 times was worth it and I now have a rough understanding of NoSQL data modelling. Hehe.